# flask-sqlalchemy, select using reverse-inclusive (not in) a set

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 3 models Post, Comments, User:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
```

my question:
how can I filter those posts those have NOT been commented by a given user(given user.id)

I have a piece of code for filtering posts those are commented by a given user:

```
@property
def commented_posts(self):
  return Post.query.join(Comment, Comment.post_id==Post.id).filter(Comment.author_id==self.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all posts where a given user has not commented on the given post:
`db.session.query(Post)\
    .filter(~exists().where(and_(Comment.author_id != some_user_id, Post.id == Comment.post_id))).all()`

This generates sql:

```
SELECT posts.id AS posts_id, posts.body AS posts_body, posts.author_id AS posts_author_id 
FROM posts 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM comments 
WHERE comments.author_id != :author_id_1 AND posts.id = comments.post_id))
```

Sample Test Code:

```
from sqlalchemy import exists, and_

u1 = User(username='User1')
u2 = User(username='User2')

db.session.add_all([u1, u2])
db.session.commit()

p1 = Post(body='Post1', author_id=u1.id, comments=[Comment(body='Comment1', author_id=u1.id),
     Comment(body='Comment2', author_id=u2.id)])
p2 = Post(body='Post2', author_id=u2.id, comments=[Comment(body='Comment3', author_id=u1.id)])
p3 = Post(body='Post3', author_id=u2.id)

db.session.add_all([p1, p2, p3])
db.session.commit()

result = db.session.query(Post)\
    .filter(~exists().where(and_(Comment.author_id != u1.id, Post.id == Comment.post_id))).all()

# Returns post  2 and post 3
print(result)

result = db.session.query(Post)\
    .filter(~exists().where(and_(Comment.author_id != u2.id, Post.id == Comment.post_id))).all()

# Returns post 3
print(result)
```